# React Native - Fix styling to avoid text overlapping with button on the same line

Tags: react-native

I am struggling with the right styles to avoid overlapping between a long text that should contain within one line or show ellipsis and some other buttons that should also show up on the same line in the app. The issue can be seen in the below sketch on Expo

https://snack.expo.io/Bk449wmAe

Below is the code for the component

```
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 50}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginVertical: 5}}>
      <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 5, overflow: 'hidden'}} numberOfLines={1}>{'Varun Gupta Varun Gupta Varun Gupta Varun Gupta'}</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 10, fontStyle: 'italic'}}>{'Creator'}</Text>
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{alignSelf: 'center', padding: 5}}>
      <Text>{'Call'}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{alignSelf: 'center', padding: 5}}>
      <Text>{'Message'}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

If you load the app, you would notice that name is overlapping the `Call` and `Message` buttons which it should not. I want the `Creator` text to stick with the name and the `Call` and `Message` buttons to appear on the far right. For e.g. if you were to reduce the name to just `Varun Gupta`, it appears as expected with the `Creator` text sticking with the name and the `Call` and `Message` appearing on the far right. If the name is too long to fit in one line, then I want to show however much would fit on one line followed by the `Creator` string followed by the two buttons. I have tried various different combinations in styling without any success. I am not sure why would the text overflow into the buttons that are present on the same line. When I inspected the elements in the `Inspector`, it appears that the `View` containing the name and the `Creator` text is sized properly but the `Text` component containing the name is going out of bounds and I am not sure how to fix it.

If I add `flex: 1` to the `<Text style={{marginHorizontal: 5, overflow: 'hidden'}} numberOfLines={1}>{'Varun Gupta Varun Gupta Varun Gupta Varun Gupta'}</Text>`, it fixes the width but then if the name is just `Varun Gupta`, `Creator` string doesn't stick with the name but appears on the far right which is expected but not desired.

Please help with the styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lodash/truncate`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#truncate) to add an ellipsis at the end of the name:

```
const name = _.truncate('Some really long name that should be truncated', { separator: ' ', length: 25 })
```

then...

```
<Text style={{marginHorizontal: 5, overflow: 'hidden'}} numberOfLines={1}>{name}></Text>
```

https://snack.expo.io/r1W-6omCg

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I want to avoid using `truncate` because then I have to make it a fixed length for all phones and I am bending towards using `numberOfLines` prop because then I don't have to think about what should be the length of each truncated field and the let the OS take care of it internally. I guess my question is more to the fact that why is the `Text` field going out of the `View` field that it is residing in and how can I avoid that.

Comment: If you want to vary the truncated text length based on device extents, try applying a percentage using `Dimensions.get('window').width`